# Show that $f(x)=\sqrt{\sin x}$ is continuous in the interval $[0,\pi]$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

[image]

How do I finish the proof? How is the denominator of the last part? Please help me and I appreciate for that.

Comment: but $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin x}+\sqrt{\sin a}}$ will be greater than $\frac{1}{2}$, not less than $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ a\gt 0 $,when $x\ge 0$,
From the second last step, you can calculate like this:
$$|\sqrt{\sin x}-\sqrt{\sin a}|\le \frac{|x-a|}{\sqrt{\sin x}+\sqrt{\sin a}} \le \frac{|x-a|}{\sqrt{\sin a}} $$
Let us choose $\epsilon \gt 0$
Then $|\sqrt{\sin x}-\sqrt{\sin a}|\lt \epsilon$ whenever $| x-a|\lt \epsilon \sqrt{\sin a}$ and $x\ge 0$.
That is ,$|\sqrt{\sin x}-\sqrt{\sin a}|\lt \epsilon$ for all $| x-a|\lt \delta$ where $\delta = \epsilon \sqrt{\sin a}$
So $\sqrt{\sin x} $ is continuous at $a$.
Also limiting value of $\sqrt{\sin x}$ at 0 is equal to its functional value, implies continuos at 0.

Comment: This answer follows from definition of continuity, for a easy approach you can use composite function concept : if $f(x)$ is continuous on an interval $I$ and $f(x) \ge 0$ for all $x\in I$,then $\sqrt{f(x)}$ is also continuous on $I$.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot. I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=\sqrt{\sin x}$ is real, finite and unique \forall  $x \in [0,\pi]$, hence it is continuous in $[0,\pi]$

Comment: Thank you! But I prefer to prove it by the definition.